# How to write an integer to stdout as hexadecimal in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

I can print an `integer` as decimal to stdout with:

```
library std;
use std.textio.all;

entity min is
end min;

architecture behav of min is
begin
    process is
        variable my_line : line;
    begin
        write(my_line, 16);
        writeline(output, my_line);
        wait;
    end process;
end behav;
```

which outputs:

```
16
```

But how to output instead either:

```
10
0x10
```

Comment: @downvoters: please explain so I can learn and improve ;-)

Comment: [Each hexadecimal digit represents four binary digits (bits)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal"). An integer scalar is a discrete type with a position that is an integer value (IEEE Std 1076-2008, 5.2 Scalar types) -  and integr doesn't have bits.  You could write a function to convert an integer value to base16 amenable to a string notation with a based literal equivalent (15.5.3), or convert an integer value to a type that does represent binary bits numerically and whose string representation has a bit string equivalent (15.8).

Answer (score 14):

Assuming an integer `i`, and VHDL-2008, you could use:

```
write(output, integer'image(i) & LF);  -- Plain integer value
write(output, "0x" & to_hstring(to_signed(i, 32)) & LF);  -- Hexadecimal representation
```

You need to have `use std.textio.all;` for this to work. Change the `32` to reduce the length of the hex value. I chose 32 so that it can represent any integer value in most simulators.

These will also work for `report` statements, e.g.

```
report "i = 0x" & to_hstring(to_signed(i, 32));
```

Comment: Can we extract that `32` computationally from the input? I know about the `integer'high` attribute, but is there something more direct?

Comment: Yes, you could use an answer like this one to compute the width required: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750007/vhdl-use-the-length-of-an-integer-generic-to-determine-number-of-select-lines/12751341#12757674

Answer (score 4):

<del>There is no standard library implementation, but</del> for example our [PoC-Libary](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC) has several formatting function in the [PoC.Strings](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/strings.vhdl#L88-L98) package. On top of that, we have a [`to_string(...)`](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/strings.vhdl#L106) function, which accepts a format character like `h` for hexadecimal outputs.

**How to write such an integer to hex conversion?**

1. Convert the INTEGER into a binary representation
2. Group the binary value into 4-bit groups
3. translate each group into an integer/alpha in range 0..F
4. prepend `0x` if wished

So here is a wrapper to convert the integer to a binary representation:

```
-- format a natural as HEX string
function raw_format_nat_hex(Value : NATURAL) return STRING is
begin
  return raw_format_slv_hex(std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(Value, log2ceil(Value+1))));
end function;
```

And now the grouping and transformation

```
-- format a std_logic_vector as HEX string
function raw_format_slv_hex(slv : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR) return STRING is
  variable Value                : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4*div_ceil(slv'length, 4) - 1 downto 0);
  variable Digit                : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
  variable Result               : STRING(1 to div_ceil(slv'length, 4));
  variable j                    : NATURAL;
begin
  Value := resize(slv, Value'length);
  j             := 0;
  for i in Result'reverse_range loop
    Digit       := Value((j * 4) + 3 downto (j * 4));
    Result(i)   := to_HexChar(unsigned(Digit));
    j           := j + 1;
  end loop;
  return Result;
end function;

-- convert an unsigned value(4 bit) to a HEX digit (0-F)
function to_HexChar(Value : UNSIGNED) return CHARACTER is
  constant HEX : STRING := "0123456789ABCDEF";
begin
  if (Value < 16) then
    return HEX(to_integer(Value)+1);
  else
    return 'X';
  end if;
end function;

-- return TRUE, if input is a power of 2
function div_ceil(a : NATURAL; b : POSITIVE) return NATURAL is  -- calculates: ceil(a / b)
begin
  return (a + (b - 1)) / b;
end function;

-- return log2; always rounded up
function log2ceil(arg : positive) return natural is
  variable tmp : positive;
  variable log : natural;
begin
  if arg = 1 then   return 0; end if;
  tmp := 1;
  log := 0;
  while arg > tmp loop
    tmp := tmp * 2;
    log := log + 1;
  end loop;
  return log;
end function;
```

*Note: These functions do not prepend `0x`.*

Comment: What, no function div_ceil?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `hwrite` procedure in the `IEEE.std_logic_textio` package:

```
library IEEE;                                                   -- ADDED
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;                                    -- ADDED
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;                                       -- ADDED
use IEEE.std_logic_textio.all;                                  -- ADDED

library std;
use std.textio.all;

entity min is
end min;

architecture behav of min is
begin
    process is
        variable my_line : line;
    begin
        hwrite(my_line, std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(16,8)));   -- CHANGED
        writeline(output, my_line);
        wait;
    end process;
end behav;
```

The `hwrite` procedure writes a `std_logic_vector` to a file. So, you do have to convert your `integer` into a `std_logic_vector`, however (which also needs you to specify a number of bits in the `to_unsigned` function).

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/exs